# How to call different function on a button based on the location it is tapped? (cocos2d, ios)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a button that performs a generic function. However, I want to call a different function if the bottom left part of the button is tapped. I just like to ask what is the better way to do this?

I am thinking of overriding ccTouchesBegan and get the location where it is tapped and perform a different function based on the bottom left position range.

Thanks!

Comment: Range? No, you want to use CGRectContainsPoint.

Comment: Might be easier to just have separate buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks LearnCocos2D for your answer (written as a comment to the question).

To answer the question:

- Define a CGRect for the bottom left part of the button.
- Then use CGRectContainsPoint to identify if the UITouch location is inside the rect or not.
  If it is, then call function2. If it is not, then call function1.